# Sublime auto indent children

Tags: pug, indentation, sublimetext, sublimetext3, stylus

Often I come to the same problem,

If I need to add a wrapper (another element to wrap elements), I have to manually select the children tab them etc...

I was wondering is there anything out there for sublime text 3, to recognise that you are indenting a parent, therefore all children should be indented automatically ?

**Edit**
I feel stylus, less and other tab based hierarchy language could suffer from the same symptoms.

Cheers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's *"Expand selection to indentation"* to select lines with the same indentation level. The default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

To add a wrapper:

- move the cursor to the first child
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to expand the selection
- indent with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
- hit <kbd>↑</kbd> to move the cursor above the selection
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a new line

[image]

Comment: I think, I would have to accept this answer :) thanks... very nice Image btw

Comment: The key combos look quite cryptic, an image is much easier to understand :) You could also record a macro if you need this frequently.